# Object being deleted when do-while starts again. How can I stop it?

Tags: c++, object, do-while

I have created a menu inside a do-while and when the user chooses what he wants to do the menu appears again. The problem is, for some choices my program has to create objects but when the menu appears again, the object is being destroyed.

Can I stop this from happening?

Here's the do while:

```
do
{
    cout << "What would you like to do?(a,b,c or d)" << endl;
    cout << "a. Add a player to a team. " << endl;
    cout << "b. View team's stats." << endl;
    cout << "c. View player's stats." << endl;
    cout << "d. Exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case'a':
        cout << "Choose team(1. maxhtes or 2. diashmoi)";
        cin >> omada;
        addPlayer(omada);
        break;
    .
    .
    .
    .
} 
while(choice != 'd');
```

And here's the function that creates the element..

```
void addPlayer(int om)
{
if(om ==1)
{
    cout << "Give Player's name,sex,occupation,age and the object he has:" 
<< endl;
    cin >>  name1 >> sex1 >> occupation1 >> age1 >> object1;
    if(maxhtes.numberOfPlayers==0)
        Player player0(name1,sex1,occupation1,age1,object1);
.
.
.
```

I've skipped the part you don't need.

Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistake. First time writing here. :)

Problem Solved: Created a global array of object and put new objects there. Thanks everyone who tried!

Comment: You certainly can't stop this from happening without showing us any code.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

Create the object OUTSIDE the do-while loop. This way, it doesn;t get destroyed when the do-while starts again.

Though showing your code would help us help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(maxhtes.numberOfPlayers==0)
    Player player0(name1,sex1,occupation1,age1,object1);
```

You're creating an object in the scope of the if statement, that object will be destroyed the moment it leaves this scope. Instead, you probably want to save it, in a vector for example:

```
std::vector<Player> players; // outer scope

//later..
if(maxhtes.numberOfPlayers==0)
    players.push_back(Player(name1,sex1,occupation1,age1,object1));
```

Comment: error: 'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type

Comment: `#include <vector>`

Comment: Still the object gets deleted